# Committed a file, but there is no change in a repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

There is a repository with tex. files. I made some changes in one of them on my computer and committed it. So, now repository got a new version number, everything is ticked green on my computer, and I cannot commit anything else, since there are no changes. The problem is that although the file is updated on my machine, it is not updated in the repository. What should I do?

Comment: A "commit" with subversion sends the change to the server as you commit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Git:**

You need to push your changes to the remote branch. Currently you just committed to your local version.

```
git push -u origin master
```

The `-u` tag just makes it so it remembers what branch you are pushing to. So next time you can just type `push`

**Using SVN:**

When you commit, SVN should do this automatically.

Comment: This. Also make sure that you have that file being tracked.

Comment: Thanks! How can I do it in tortoise?

Comment: Strangely, now the repository is updated, although I did nothing. Is it okay, that it took several minutes to update?

Comment: Sometimes it takes a minute to update on the web pages. If it worked, I wouldn't worry too much.